# How to store native timestamp type data while using Eve REST API for MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, rest, post, timestamp, eve

In the Mongo Rest API **"Eve(0.7.4v)"** , how can I insert a native Mongodb field type like timestamp with a POST request

Here is the Eve schema used:

```
DOMAIN = {'middlewaredata': {'timestamp':{'type':'datetime'}}}

MONGO_DBNAME  = 'helloworld'


# Enable reads (GET), inserts (POST) and DELETE for resources/collections
# (if you omit this line, the API will default to ['GET'] and provide
# read-only access to the endpoint).
RESOURCE_METHODS = ['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE']

# Enable reads (GET), edits (PATCH), replacements (PUT) and deletes of
# individual items  (defaults to read-only item access).
ITEM_METHODS = ['GET', 'PATCH', 'PUT', 'DELETE']

ALLOW_UNKNOWN=True
```

Here is the sample code

```
import requests,datetime,json

header={'ContentType':'application/json'}
payload=json.dumps({"name":"helloworld","timestamp":datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat()}
requests.post("http://locahost:5000/data",headers=header,data=payload)
```

This creates the following document in the Mongodb collection named "data"

```
{
"_id": ObjectID("5a26d12a921409307490cd4f"),
"timestamp": "2017-12-04T16:51:25.632389",
"_etag": "a3bc176e34818bd9e4af57a77c11919dbc394c7a",
"_created": ISODate("2017-12-05T17:02:34.000Z")
}
```

Instead I want this to be inserted as shown below -

```
{
"_id": ObjectID("5a26d12a921409307490cd4f"),
"timestamp": ISODate("2017-12-04T16:51:25.632389"),
"_etag": "a3bc176e34818bd9e4af57a77c11919dbc394c7a",
"_created": ISODate("2017-12-05T17:02:34.000Z")
}
```

Comment: What is your schema definition for this `data` document? You need to set `timestamp` field type as `datetime`

Comment: @gcw .. I have added the schema in the question, "timestamp" field is already of "datetime" type.

Answer (score 1):

The `DATE_FORMAT` setting allows you to set the format of datetime values. From the [documentation](http://python-eve.org/config.html):

> A Python date format used to parse and render datetime values. When serving requests, **matching JSON strings will be parsed and stored as datetime values**. In responses, datetime values will be rendered as JSON strings using this format. Defaults to the RFC1123 (ex RFC 822) standard a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT (“Tue, 02 Apr 2013 10:29:13 GMT”).

So, unless you change the default setting, you want to provide RFC-1123 formatted strings, such as "Tue, 02 Apr 2013 10:29:13 GMT".

Comment: I just tried with this curl command and it doensn't store the timestamp in the native datetime format.. All Eve settings are as posted in question.

    curl -d '{"firstname": "mitt", "lastname": "romney","timestamp":"Tue, 02 Apr 2013 10:29:13 GMT"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'  http://localhost:5000/middlewaredata -v

Here is the stored data -

Comment: `{
    "_id": ObjectID("5a27e93a9214097338d778f7"),
    "_updated": ISODate("2017-12-06T12:57:30.000Z"),
    "firstname": "mitt",
    "lastname": "romney",
    "timestamp": "Tue, 02 Apr 2013 10:29:13 GMT",
    "_created": ISODate("2017-12-06T12:57:30.000Z"),
    "_etag": "6b56643bcebacbe21e55e70cc7e2e17e74b64280"
}`


**BTW : I am using Eve 0.7.4**

Answer (score 1):

By default eve [DATE_FORMAT is set to RFC1123](http://docs.python-eve.org/en/latest/config.html) standard which is `%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT` (In documentation a is missing %). You can change default in settings.py

Now to post your time to eve endpoint, you have to create exactly this kind of string. And EXACTLY like this. It has to have that GMT also at the end or you will get "must be of datetime type" error.

### Example with string and datetime.now()

```
from datetime import datetime
import json
import requests

date_string = '2012-01-01'

#create datetime object
date = datetime.strptime(date_string, '%Y-%m-%d') 

#format it
eve_friendly = date.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT")

#can have it in oneliner
datetime.strptime(date_string, '%Y-%m-%d').strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT")

#example with datetime.now()
now_time = datetime.now().strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT") 

#post it
header={'ContentType':'application/json'}
payload=json.dumps({"timestamp": now_time})
requests.post("http://locahost:5000/data",headers=header,data=payload)
```

I struggled for a while to figure this one ;)